# combine ner_tags and tokens with respect to them tigether

Tags: list, tags, token, entity, named

list 1 = ['MOHAMMED', 'KARIMULLAH', 'RAHIMULLAH', 'MOHAMMED', '25/10/1965', 'AQFPM7006F', 'आयकर', 'विभाग', 'INCOME', 'TAX', 'DEPARTMENT', 'भारत', 'सरकार', 'GOVT.', 'OF', 'INDIA']

list 2 = ['B-name', 'I-name', 'B-fathernm', 'I-fathernm', 'B-dob', 'B-accnum', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']

two lists with tokens in first list and ner_tags with respect to list 1

mohamed karimullah is one name but is separated .
How to combine the name as one wrt to b-name and i-name?